# Ansible append directory with file content weird behavior

Tags: ansible

I try to append the contents of two key files into a directory and while doing that I get weird data.

```
- name: read server privkey
  slurp:
    src: "{{ directories.serverkeys.dir }}server-private.key"
  register: filecontents
- name: set server privkey
  set_fact:
    server: "{{ server|combine({'privkey': '{{ filecontents.content }}'}, recursive=True) }}"
- name: debug
  debug: var=server
```

This outputs:

```
    ok: [localhost] => {
    "server": {
        "ip": "10.10.10.1/24",
        "privkey": "aVBDYjErODlQek9rVlM1Y2t1SGpYbUlNdWxVM0t3NHBUaTZ2M2FJTFJuaz0K"
    }
}
```

When I try to read the public key as well I get weird output

```
    #Set server output for template
- name: read server privkey
  slurp:
    src: "{{ directories.serverkeys.dir }}server-private.key"
  register: privatekey
- name: set server privkey
  set_fact:
    server: "{{ server|combine({'privkey': '{{ privatekey.content }}'}, recursive=True) }}"
- name: read server pubkey
  slurp:
    src: "{{ directories.serverkeys.dir }}server-public.key"
  register: publickey
- name: set server pubkey
  set_fact:
    server: "{{ server|combine({'pubkey': '{{ publickey.content }}'}, recursive=True) }}"
- name: debug
  debug: var=server
```

which outputs:

```
    ok: [localhost] => {
    "server": { 
        "ip": "10.10.10.1/24",
        "privkey": "aVBDYjErODlQek9rVlM1Y2t1SGpYbUlNdWxVM0t3NHBUaTZ2M2FJTFJuaz0K", 
        "pubkey": "{{ publickey.content }}"
    }
}
```

So this is weird, why does the second set_fact set a string and not substitute for the variable. when I switch the order, I get the same output on the vice versa variable. I don't understand this behavior, can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are using the double bracket notation while already inside a jinja2 expression. Here is the right syntax:

```
  - name: read server privkey
    slurp:
      src: "file"
    register: privatekey
  - name: set server privkey
    set_fact:
      server: "{{ server|combine({'privkey': privatekey.content}, recursive=True) }}"
  - name: debug
    debug: var=server

  - name: read server pubkey
    slurp:
      src: "file"
    register: publickey
  - name: set server pubkey
    set_fact:
      server: "{{ server|combine({'pubkey': publickey.content}, recursive=True) }}"
  - name: debug
    debug: var=server
```

Note: It's still weird that the first assignment differs from the 2nd one in the playbook you provided though. I think that might be a bug?

Comment: No thats not it. If I add b64decode the output of  pubkey is still the string {{filecontents.content | b64decode}} I was not wondering about base64, but why the second call does not output the contents of the variable, BUT the callstring of the variable

Comment: This was a syntax issue. However, the behavior you showed is still really weird...